# Django - Query extended models effeciently

Tags: python, django, database, orm

I have a BaseModel(models.Model), and ExtendedModelA(BaseModel) and ExtendedModelB(BaseModel). ExtendedModelA and ExtendedModelB both have foreign key fields to other models. Their **unicode** methods return a field from this foreign key related model.

I have a dropdown menu which I want to populate with BaseModel objects (which  naturally includes ExtendedModelA and ExtendedModelB objects). To do this I need a queryset which will get all extended objects (type A and B) and their related objects.

I have a merged queryset:

```
queryset = BaseModel.objects.filter(type=1).select_related('extendedmodela') | BaseModel.objects.filter(type=2).select_related('extendedmodelb')
```

The trouble is that the unicode representation of the BaseModel is presented in the dropdown. If I add a unicode method to the BaseModel class which has conditions:

```
    if hasattr(self, extendedmodela):
        return self.extendedmodela.__unicode__()
    else:
        return self.extendedmodelb.__unicode__()
```

This results in querying the database for each object.

Anyone any ideas about how to get myself out of this mess?

Essentially I need to formulate a queryset which will get all BaseModel objects efficiently, and when they're displaying in the dropdown their unicode methods for their respective extended classes (which print fields from a foreign key field object) dont hammer the database. I have a few thousand objects so the database takes a hit.

Cheers,

Dean

Comment: Can't you just have mixed list/set of `ExtendedModelA/B` instances?

Comment: I'm not sure - pretty new to Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `select_related`, which is good. I think you can optimize your query by using a `Q`, which essentially lets you filter for *either* type 1 or type 2 in this case.

```
from django.db.models import Q

BaseModel.objects.filter(Q(type=1) | Q(type=2)).select_related('extendedmodela').select_related('extendedmodelb')
```

**EDIT**

You can use the double-underscore notation to access deeper fields that are on related models. eg.

```
 .select_related('extendedmodela', 'extendedmodela__fkfieldname')
```

Comment: This will not help the fact that the unicode methods of A and B will access foreign keys that will have to be retrieved one by one. You can append the necessary relations to your existing `select_related` though.

Comment: So in order to solve the problem of the unicode foreign key call I just add more 'select_related' to this query can pass in the able names where the foreign keys link to?

Comment: @DeanSherwin You can use the double-underscore notation to reach the deeper fields that are from related models.

Comment: I'm a little confused what the actual problem is though.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Can you describe how I would 2append the necessary relations to your existing select_related" please?

Comment: This works! Got it working with some googling. I used .select_related('extendedmodela', 'extendedmodela__fkfieldname'). So basically I used double underscore notation to fix the many db calls the  foreign key unicode issue was causing! If you edit your answer I'll mark it correct. :)

Comment: @DeanSherwin glad it worked out. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass a mixed bag to the dropdown. This is no longer a `QuerySet`, but the dropdown won't mind:

```
qs = list(ExtendedModelA.objects.select_related('whatever_fk_needed')) +\
     list(ExtendedModelB.objects.select_related('whatever_fk_needed'))
```

Whatever instance is selected, will have the same `id` as its `BaseModel` instance.

Comment: I woudln't do this because changing to a list will cause the queryset to be evaluated. You could use `values_list` instead.

Comment: The queryset will be evaluated anyway as soon as the dropdown is rendered.

Comment: I guess that's true.

Comment: Would this resolve the DB calls for each object from the extended classes' unicode methods which gets a field from a foreign key relation though?

Comment: Yup. You would have to have a `select_related` for each `ForeignKey` used in the respective `unicode`.